# How to define a class in Ruby when using Sequel?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, sequel

I am using Ruby with Sinatra and Sequel. Now I am trying to create classes for my project, for example the class "User" which should contain "First Name" and "Lastname". When creating an instance of that class it should be possible to directly set the names like `new User("Some","name")`.
I am using Sequel to connect to a database and create a class::model like this:

```
class User < Sequel::Model end
```

My question is now where would I add a constructor for my class User and define all the variables? As I allready have the Sequel::Model "User" I can not create another class "User" but I can on the other hand not add a constructor to the Sequel::Model class because that would create a new dataset for each instance of the User class, wouldn´t it? I am confused.

**If that was a bit difficult to understand here the short version: I have a file containing a class "User" which inherits Sequel::Model. Where would I put the class variables like name or id and methods like "do_something_with_a_specific_user()"?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Where would I put the class variables like name or id and methods like …

For attributes that are in the table, you don't. When the database is loaded, the `User` class will be built using information inferred from the `users` table in the database. If you have an `id` field, then model instances will get an `id` attribute etc etc. If you need extra attributes that aren't in the table, by all means just add them in the usual way. Same goes for methods.

Also, the syntax you'd use to create a new model instance would be more like `user = User.new name: "php", lastname: "heini"`

See http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc/files/README_rdoc.html#label-Sequel+Models

---

Be careful with the word "create" when talking about models, because there is creation of a record in the database and creation of an instance, but most people would expect "create" to refer to the first, not (only) the last. `new` is a good synonym for "create", hence it leads to a new record in the database (if you `save` it, otherwise just use [`create`](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc/files/README_rdoc.html#label-Creating+new+records)). If you want to get an instance (i.e. a record) then either capture the instance when calling `new`, or retrieve an existing record. There are plenty of ways to retrieve records, but `[]` is one you'll use a lot. It makes sense as a choice, since arrays and hashes use that syntax for record retrieval too.

```
class User < Sequel::Model

  def fullname
    "#{self.firstname} #{self.lastname}"
  end
end

# add your first user
u1 = User.new firstname: "Bill", lastname: "Flowerpot"

u1.fullname
# => "Bill Flowerpot"

u1.save

u1.id
# => 1

# retrieve it later by index
u1 = User[1]

# Retrieve a user (that has already been added to the db)
# by some other unique value
u2 => User[firstname: "Ben"]
u2.fullname
# => "Ben Flowerpot"
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I just still don´t understand where do I put methods that apply to a user? Into the User class or somewhere else?

And what do you mean by "usual way"? Imagine I would like to have an instance of my User class for each User I have, I could not just create new users with `User.new` because that would create new datasets each time...

Comment: @phpheini Are you new to Ruby? If so, I suggest you take a quick look at how to create a standard class *before* working with Sequel.

Comment: yes I am new, I have looked at this http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/writing_our_own_class_in_ruby.html but that doesn´t answer my question.